# Can not use i letter to search bring words start with capital i letter

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I am working on a search page with turkish characters, problem is with small i letter When user enters i, it does not bring words starting with İ (capital i in turkish) because of some code(toUpperCase) makes it I (capital i in english)

I tried to implement my own uppercase function instead of using toUpperCase but did not work.

```
        return this.options.filter(item => {
          // this.search = this.search.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)
           return this.capitalize(item.name).indexOf(self.search.toUpperCase()) !== -1
          // return item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.search.toUpperCase()) !== -1 // this is the original line that works except for letter i
        })
```

these are my custom capitalize functions

```
    capitalize1 (s) {
      return s.charAt(0).replace('i', 'İ')
      return s.charAt(0).replace('ı', 'I')
      return s.charAt(0).replace('ü', 'Ü')
      return s.charAt(0).replace('a', 'A')
      return s.charAt(0).replace('b', 'c')
    },
 capitalize(search) {
           if (search.substring(0,1) === 'i') {
             search = search.replace('i', 'İ')
            // search = this.capitalize1(self.search)
            return search
          } else {
    var firstChar = search.charCodeAt(0);
    if (firstChar >= 97 && firstChar <= 122) {
        return String.fromCharCode(firstChar - 32) + word.substr(1);
    }
    return search;
          }


}
```

I expect it to brings words starting with capital i (İ) but not bring, or not bring anyting et all (with my custom capitalize functions)

Comment: if you are just trying to compare: `['İ'].filter(chr => chr.localeCompare('i') == 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use toLocaleUpperCase

Please refer this link for more details from MDN- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase
**Syntax:**

```
string.toLocaleUpperCase('TR')
```